# Scopes in blank function c++

Tags: c++

Hy, my question is simple..
I have this function.

```
CPythonMessenger::CPythonMessenger(): m_poMessengerHandler(NULL)
{
}
```

What scope have and why is there since constructor is empty and also is not used `m_poMessengerHandler(NULL)` i want to say the function is not used anywhere is constructor.

Comment: Hard to tell from the snippet what you actually want. It seems you need to call `m_poMessengerHandler(NULL)`, because there's no default constructor for this member. Scope in the constructor body is `class CPythonMessenger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are examining (or maybe it is your code) [THIS](https://github.com/adi97ida/Client/blob/master/UserInterface/PythonMessenger.cpp).

`CPythonMessenger` is the default constructor for the class `CPythonMessenger` as you can see in the relative header file [HERE](https://github.com/adi97ida/Client/blob/master/UserInterface/PythonMessenger.h). After the `:` you can invoke a method (or another constructor) that must be run when creating an object of `CPythonMessenger` type. In particular, it creates an instance of `m_poMessengerHandler` that is then used in several place in the other class methods.